Ubuntu 18.0.4 fails to start after manual reboot
I have rebooted my ubuntu manually, but it is failing to start again. It stays on the ubuntu logo:
I tried the recovery mod and ran file disk check. Then choose resume to continue normal startup. But I ended up here:

And it didn't continue to anywhere. So, I have to power off the laptop with power button. Now, this is the screen:


the first seven lines of your second screenshot are the end of a kernel crash report. So, your kernel crashes – that's bad. And it's very likely not a driver quality issue – Lenovo thinkpads are usually very well-tested when it comes to that.
The first thing you should do here is making a backup of the data in your home directory. The rest can probably be restored, but I guess you have important documents there!
To do so, you'd get a Linux system that can boot off a USB drive (there's many to choose from!). Put it on the USB drive (with another computer), then boot your laptop from that USB drive. Open the file manager, find your internal laptop drive, find the home directory within that, and make a copy to an external storage device – an external hard drive / SSD, another USB stick (if large enough), online storage.
NO matter how you solve the issue: this is the step you must do, or you will be very sad. No discussion, honestly, if you value any of the data you have on that laptop!
While and after copying the data off the internal drive, watch the output of sudo dmesg -Hwx in a terminal window. If you see any error appearing like "failed to read block" or "resetting device", then your internal drive is broken and needs to be replaced (there's no redeeming it in that case, don't try.). Luckily, replacing the internal drive in an E480 is really easy (you need only 1 screwdriver and a new SSD, and these are cheap).
So, honestly, after you have that backup of your important data:
Ubuntu 18.04 is really old by now, you have quite a good laptop, and you should probably just install a newer version of Ubuntu. If the live system you chose to do your backup was the Ubuntu 24.04 installer, then you could first do your backup, then use it to remove all partitions from your internal storage (if it's not broken), install a fresh Ubuntu 24.04, and then copy the files from your backup back to your internal drive.
